# search from a column to get the count of various data

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Here is my table `emp` :

```
+---------+------------------+
| emp     |  id      | color |
+---------+------------------+
| hary    | 123      |  red  |
+---------+------------------+
| lary    | 125      | green |
+---------+------------------+
| gary    | 038      |  red  |
+---------+------------------+
| Kris    | 912      | blue  |
+---------+------------------+
| hary    | 123      |  red  |
+---------+------------------+
| Ronn    | 334      | green |
+---------+------------------+
```

Now I want to find out the count of each colour i.e red,green and blue;

On this context I'm trying to write down the query in terms of `where color like '%bl%',like '%ree%',like %ed%.` and to want this result

```
+--------------------------+
| red | blue | green       |
+--------------------------+
|   3 |   1  |  2          | 
+--------------------------+
```

I have tried this thing:

```
    select count(case when color='green' then 1 end) as Green,count(case when 
color='blue' then 1 end) as Blue,count(case when color='Red' then 1 end) as Red from emp;
```

I don't want to hardcode their name(as I'll use it in my code jdbc).
I'll appreciate any input's regarding this questain.

Comment: First answer is what you need for your pivot view.. e.g. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4131/7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select color,count(*) clrCount
from emp 
group by color
```

with where clause

```
select color,count(*) clrCount
from emp where (color like '%bl%' or color like '%ree%')
group by color
```

Comment: But I want to use this "color like '%bl%',like '%ree%',like %ed%" in my query. any inputs

Comment: you can add where condition in the above query with all the conditions

Comment: could you please explain in your answer.

Comment: select color,count(*) as clrCount from emp where (color like '%bl%' or color like '%ree%') group by color. Use **as** for displaying the header

Comment: brilliant answer anand, thank you an this community for their support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
select color,count(*) from emp group by color;
```